# Mongoose is connecting to localhost instead of my connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am moving from localhost to using mongodb-atlas to host my database. I changed the connection string in my nodejs application, but every time the app is supposed to create a new document on the atlas server its creating it on the localhost still.

I made sure the new connection string was everywhere. I tried creating a new user as well.

Function code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Report = require("../models/report.js")
const { mongoURL } = require('../config.json');
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, {useNewUrlParser: true});


module.exports = {
    name: 'testreport',
    description: 'test  report',
    args: true,
    usage: '<user> <reason>',
    async execute(message, args) {
        let rUser = message.mentions.members.first();
        let rreason = args;
        const report = new Report({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            username: rUser.user.username,
            userID: rUser.id,
            reason: rreason,
            rUsername: message.author.username,
            rID: message.author.id,
            time: message.createdAt
        })

        report.save()
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

        message.reply("that report has been saved!");
    },
};
```

Schema code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { mongoURL } = require('../config.json');
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, {useNewUrlParser: true});
const reportSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    userID: String,
    reason: String,
    rUsername: String,
    rID: String,
    time: String

}, { collection: 'Reports' })

module.exports = mongoose.model("Report", reportSchema);
```

Connection String:

"mongodb+srv://user:pass@discordbot-rpuzu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"

I expect my atlas database to receive a new report document, but it is being created on my localhost database.

Edit:
I have gotten it working, but every time I start the application I get a

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

I do not understand why forcequiting localhost fixed the issue and why I am still receiving warning that localhost isn't up and running.

Comment: What does `console.log(mongoURL)` show?

Comment: It's displaying the correct URL that is being grabbed from config.

Comment: Well if its saving to localhost db you've obviously got the wrong connection string somewhere.

Comment: Did you stop the server and restart it after updating the URI?

Comment: You've two `mongoUrl` imported. looking at this import `const Report = require("../models/report.js")`, your files seem to be in different folders but your `mongoUrl` import is the same `const { mongoURL } = require('../config.json');` Are you sure you're importing the *same* `config.json`?

Comment: I've stopped my nodejs app and restarted it a few times. Is there someway to stop mongodb on locahost?

Comment: I have used console.log(mongoURL) and it appears correct so it is definitely getting the correct url.

Comment: I think @naga-elixir-jar has got it right. You should only be calling `mongoose.connect` once anyway, so remove that line from the "schema code".

Comment: So I forcequit mongodb on my computer so it couldn't get to localhost anymore. And I am now getting a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server localhost